# Onvif Event Subscription in C#

Tags: c#, events, onvif

I am implementing an ipCamera/encoder management system in C#. The system will manage multiple ipCameras and/or encoders from a multiple vendors. Using Onvif instead off each ipcamera or encoders sdk will be a benefit.

One of the key concepts of the management system is to listen on events, such as motion detection events, from the cameras. Onvif supports this by use of the ws-basenotification or a pull type support. I don’t like pull, so I will use ws-basenotification support in Onvif (Onvif spec 9.1).

I have successfully added subscription to a Sony SNC-RH164, Bosh VIP X1 XF IVA and  Acti TCD2100.

My problem is: I don’t get any notifications from any of the devices. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or give my som pointers on how to get notifications from devices.
My pc is on the same subnet as the devices. And my firewall is turned off for the test.

My test console app initiating the OnvifManager class.

```
using (var manager = new OnvifManager())
        {
            //manager.ScanForDevices();
            var sonyDevice = new OnvifClassLib.OnvifDevice
            {
                OnvifDeviceServiceUri = new Uri(@"http://192.168.0.101/onvif/device_service"),

            };
            manager.AddDevice(sonyDevice);
            manager.AddEventSubscription(sonyDevice, "PT1H");

            var boshDevice = new OnvifClassLib.OnvifDevice
            {
                OnvifDeviceServiceUri = new Uri(@"http://192.168.0.102/onvif/device_service"),


            };
            manager.AddDevice(boshDevice);
            manager.AddEventSubscription(boshDevice, string.Empty);

            var actiDevice = new OnvifClassLib.OnvifDevice
            {
                OnvifDeviceServiceUri = new Uri(@"http://192.168.0.103/onvif/device_service"),
                UserName = "uid",
                Password = "pwd"

            };
            manager.AddDevice(actiDevice);
            manager.AddEventSubscription(actiDevice);

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
            Console.Read();
        }
```

My managerClass will in the Constructor initialize my NotificationConsumer interface.

```
private void InitializeNotificationConsumerService()
    {
        _notificationConsumerService = new NotificationConsumerService();
        _notificationConsumerService.NewNotification += NotificationConsumerService_OnNewNotification;
        _notificationConsumerServiceHost = new ServiceHost(_notificationConsumerService);
        _notificationConsumerServiceHost.Open();
    }
```

My NotificationConsumer interface implementation.

```
 /// <summary>
/// The client reciever service for WS-BaseNotification
/// </summary>
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class NotificationConsumerService : NotificationConsumer
{

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<Notify1>> NewNotification;

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the specified request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request.</param>
    /// <remarks>A </remarks>
    public void Notify(Notify1 request)
    {
        var threadSafeEventHandler = NewNotification;
        if (threadSafeEventHandler != null)
            threadSafeEventHandler.Invoke(this, new EventArgs<Notify1>(request));
    }
}

public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{

    public EventArgs(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

The config for NotificationConsumerService

```
<services>
  <service name="OnvifClassLib.NotificationConsumerService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBasicHttpBinding"
      name="CustomHttpBinding" contract="EventService.NotificationConsumer" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.0.10:8080/NotificationConsumerService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>      
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBasicHttpBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="80000" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="800000" maxBufferSize="800000" />
    </binding>        
  </customBinding>      
</bindings>
```

The AddDevice method

```
public void AddDevice(OnvifDevice device)
    {
        LoadCapabilities(device);
        OnvifDevices.Add(device);
    }


internal void LoadCapabilities(OnvifDevice onvifDevice)
    {
        if (onvifDevice.OnvifDeviceServiceUri == null)
            return;
        if (onvifDevice.DeviceClient == null)
            LoadDeviceClient(onvifDevice);
        try
        {

            onvifDevice.Capabilities = onvifDevice.DeviceClient.GetCapabilities(new[] { OnvifClassLib.DeviceManagement.CapabilityCategory.All });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        }


    }
private void LoadDeviceClient(OnvifDevice onvifDevice)
    {

        if (onvifDevice.OnvifDeviceServiceUri == null)
            return;

        var serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress(onvifDevice.OnvifDeviceServiceUri.ToString());
        var binding = GetBindingFactory(onvifDevice);
        onvifDevice.DeviceClient = new OnvifClassLib.DeviceManagement.DeviceClient(binding, serviceAddress);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(onvifDevice.UserName))
        {
            onvifDevice.DeviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = onvifDevice.UserName;
            onvifDevice.DeviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = onvifDevice.Password;
        }

    }
```

The AddEventSubscription method

```
 public void AddEventSubscription(OnvifDevice onvifDevice, string initialTerminationTime = "PT2H")
    {
        if (onvifDevice.Capabilities.Events == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("The streamer info does not support event");
        try
        {


            if (onvifDevice.NotificationProducerClient == null)
                LoadNotificationProducerClient(onvifDevice);

            XmlElement[] filterXml = null;


            var subScribe = new Subscribe()
            {
                ConsumerReference = new EndpointReferenceType
                {
                    Address = new AttributedURIType { Value = _notificationConsumerServiceHost.BaseAddresses.First().ToString() },

                }

            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(initialTerminationTime))
                subScribe.InitialTerminationTime = initialTerminationTime;


            onvifDevice.SubscribeResponse = onvifDevice.NotificationProducerClient.Subscribe(subScribe);

            Console.WriteLine("Listening on event from {0}", onvifDevice.NotificationProducerClient.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString());
        }

        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

private void LoadNotificationProducerClient(OnvifDevice onvifDevice)
    {
        var serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress(onvifDevice.Capabilities.Events.XAddr.ToString());
        var binding = GetBindingFactory(onvifDevice);
        onvifDevice.NotificationProducerClient = new OnvifClassLib.EventService.NotificationProducerClient(binding, serviceAddress);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(onvifDevice.UserName))
        {
            onvifDevice.NotificationProducerClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = onvifDevice.UserName;
            onvifDevice.NotificationProducerClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = onvifDevice.Password;
        }
    }
```

Bindings for Soap12

```
private Binding GetBindingFactory(OnvifDevice onvifDevice)
    {            
        return GetCustomBinding(onvifDevice);
    }
private Binding GetCustomBinding(OnvifDevice onvifDevice)
    {
        HttpTransportBindingElement transportElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(onvifDevice.UserName))
            transportElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;


        var messegeElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        messegeElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);

        var binding = new CustomBinding(messegeElement, transportElement);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        return binding;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a GrandStream camera. I had to add one or more detection zones to it using the camera web UI to get it to detect motion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that your notification consumer uses `AddressingVersion.None`, while the notifications from the ONVIF device are formatted according to WS-Addressing 1.0.  Try to change the following line of your GetCustomBinding method:

```
messegeElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(
    EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);
```

to

```
messegeElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(
    EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.WSAddressing10);
```