# Events not being thrown by ONVIF camera

Tags: c#, events, onvif

I have several ONVIF compliant camera's and encoders that I want to receive events from, e.g. motion alarm.

So far I managed to subscribe (I think) with the events wsdl but no events are ever thrown. I checked the settings in the device to make sure it uses motion detection and I can hear a relay flip when motion is present so the settings are correct.

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563403/onvif-event-subscription-in-c-sharp) as a reference for my attempt but since it didn't get an accepted awnser I will ask it again.

Here's how I set up my wsdl files:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://" + CameraInformation.IpAddress + "/onvif/device_service");
HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement { AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest };
httpTransportBinding.KeepAliveEnabled = true;
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncodingBinding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.WSAddressing10) };
PasswordDigestBehavior passwordDigestBehavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(CameraInformation.Username, CameraInformation.Password);

CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(textMessageEncodingBinding, httpTransportBinding);
customBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
```

Here's how I initialize my consumer service:

```
_notificationConsumerService = new NotificationConsumerService();
_notificationConsumerService.NewNotification += _notificationConsumerService_NewNotification;
_notificationConsumerServiceHost = new ServiceHost(_notificationConsumerService, new Uri("http://localhost:8085/NotificationConsumerService"));
_notificationConsumerServiceHost.Open();
```

the NotificationConsumerService class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class NotificationConsumerService : OnvifEvents.NotificationConsumer
{
      public event EventHandler<EventArgs<OnvifEvents.Notify1>> NewNotification;

      public void Notify(OnvifEvents.Notify1 request)
      {
          var threadSafeEventHandler = NewNotification;
          if (threadSafeEventHandler != null)
              threadSafeEventHandler.Invoke(this, new EventArgs<OnvifEvents.Notify1>(request));
      }

      public Task NotifyAsync(System21.OnvifEvents.Notify1 request)
      {
         return new Task(() =>
            {
                 //return something?
            });
     }
}

     public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
     {
        public EventArgs(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }
        public T Data { get; set; }
     }
```

Loading the notification producer client:

```
    var serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress(Capabilities.Events.XAddr.ToString());
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CameraInformation.Username))
    {
         NotificationProducerClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = CameraInformation.Username;
         NotificationProducerClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = CameraInformation.Password;
    }
```

and finally add the event subscription:

```
if (Capabilities.Events == null)
      throw new ApplicationException("The streamer info does not support event");
try
{
       if (NotificationProducerClient == null)
            LoadNotificationProducerClient();

       var subScribe = new OnvifEvents.Subscribe()
       {
            ConsumerReference = new OnvifEvents.EndpointReferenceType
            {
                  Address = new OnvifEvents.AttributedURIType { Value = _notificationConsumerServiceHost.BaseAddresses.First().ToString() },
            }
       };
       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(initialTerminationTime))
            subScribe.InitialTerminationTime = initialTerminationTime;

       OnvifEvents.SubscribeResponse response = NotificationProducerClient.Subscribe(subScribe);
}

Catch (FaultException ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
}
```

A possible awnser from the related question was that the AddressingVersion was set to None when it's supposed to be set to WSAddressing10 but I encountered this earlier so it's not a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think relay flip you feel is about IR mode not motion detect.Try to open your camera in [ODM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/). Its an open source implementation of ONVIF discovery and events subscriptions.

Comment: The relay flip really is triggered by motion detection (the device has output pins that you can use for motion detection). I used ODM to see if the device actually throws events and it does.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant, but just by looking at this code, shouldn't the call

```
_notificationConsumerServiceHost = new ServiceHost(_notificationConsumerService, new Uri("http://localhost:8085/NotificationConsumerService"));
```

be something like:

```
_notificationConsumerServiceHost = new ServiceHost(_notificationConsumerService, new Uri("http://<RemoteIP>:8085/NotificationConsumerService"));
```

i.e. the "localhost" may not resolve the host on the camera in which case the call request gets lost.